# windows cmd for loop cycle and time counting + percentage

Tags: for-loop, time, cmd, percentage, counting

First i was looking for a code if already exist here or elsewhere,
but found no result with my requirements.
So i started to build it up part by part.
I set few things like getting total number,
than create temp file if not exist.
If file with the record exist than set record of how much is done
,after put that in a loop cycle "for"
and count everything to show results also with the percentage.

So this is actually the result of what i have done.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
set /p NUMBER=<total_number.info
set INFO_FILE=total_done.info
IF NOT EXIST %INFO_FILE% (
    (echo 1) > %INFO_FILE%
)
set /p NUMBER_DONE=<%INFO_FILE%
for /l %%x in (%NUMBER_DONE%, 1, %NUMBER%) do (
    set /a "Total_Left=%NUMBER%-%%x"
    set /a "percent=(%%x*100)/%NUMBER%"
    if !Total_Left! GEQ 1 (
        set /a "Seconds=!Total_Left!*2"
    ) else (
        set /a "Seconds=00"
    )
    if !Seconds! GEQ 60 (
        set /a "Minutes=!Seconds!/60"
    ) else (
        set /a "Minutes=00"
    )
    if !Minutes! GEQ 60 (
        set /a "Hours=!Minutes!/60"
    ) else (
        set /a "Hours=00"
    )
    if !Hours! GEQ 24 (
        set /a "Days=!Hours!/24"
    ) else (
        set /a "Days=0"
    )
    set /a "T_L_H=!Hours!-(!Days!*24)"
    set /a "T_L_M=!Minutes!-(!Hours!*60)"
    set /a "T_L_S=!Seconds!-(!Minutes!*60)"
    set "T_L_Ho=0!T_L_H!"
    set "T_L_Mi=0!T_L_M!"
    set "T_L_Se=0!T_L_S!"
    TITLE Test - Percent done : !percent!%%
    echo.
    echo Time Left : !Days! Days !T_L_Ho:~-2!:!T_L_Mi:~-2!:!T_L_Se:~-2!
    echo.
    echo Total pages to be done : %NUMBER%
    echo Pages done : %%x
    echo Rest of the pages : !Total_Left!
    echo Percent done : !percent!%%
    if %%x GEQ %NUMBER_DONE% (
        (echo %%x) > %INFO_FILE%
        timeout 1 > NUL
    )
    cls
)
pause>NUL
```

Script last time updated 12.1.2018 23:45

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell script that will monitor progress using a file containing the current step number. Be sure to create the watch file before starting it.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
This cmdlet displays a progress bar based on monitoring a watch file.

.DESCRIPTION
If no PROMPT string is provided, the $Env:PROMPT string will be used.

.PARAMETER TotalCount
Specify the total number of steps to monitor.

.PARAMETER WatchFile
Specify the path to the file containing the number of steps completed.

.EXAMPLE
Monitor-Progress -TotalCount 10 -WatchFile wf.txt
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]$TotalCount

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf'})]
    [string]$WatchFile
)

$currentcount = 0
$previouscount = $currentcount

while ($currentcount -lt $TotalCount) {
    $currentcount = [int32](Get-Content $WatchFile)

    if ($currentcount -ne $previouscount) {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Watching long progress" `
            -percentComplete ($currentcount / $TotalCount*100)
        $previouscount = $currentcount
    }
}
```

If you need to run this from the cmd.exe shell, you can:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File Monitor-Progress.ps1 -TotalCount 5 -WatchFile wf.txt
```